# null value in column "id" of relation "messages" violates not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

When `nodejs 14.x/sequelize 6.5.x` save a `message`, it throws an strange error:

> Error in saving/braodcasting a new message DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: null value in column "id" of relation "messages" violates not-null constraint

Here is the table structure of `message`:

[image]

Here is the instance of `message` to be saved:

```
        let msg = Message.build();
        msg.sender_id = req.viewer.id;
        msg.room_id = room_id;
        msg.type = type;
        msg.set("data.msg_body", req.body.data.msg_body);  
        console.log("new message post msg : ", msg);
  
        await msg.save();  //<<== throws error about null id
```

Since column `id` can not be null and the id was assigned during `msg.save()`, what the error is really complaining about and how to fix it?

Here is the model def:

```
const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const Op = DataTypes.Op;
const db = require("../startup/db");
const Joi = require('joi');

class Message extends Model {};
Message.init({
    
    room_id: {type: DataTypes.STRING,  //[s,t]idfort-token(seller or poster's)]
               allowNull:false,
    },
    sender_id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull:false,    
                validate: {
                    isInt:true,
                },
    },
    type:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    receiver_id : {type: DataTypes.INTEGER},
    data: {
        type: DataTypes.JSONB,
        validate: {
            validateJSONData(value) {
                let counter = 0;
                for (key in value) {
                    if (value[key] !== null) {
                        ++counter;
                    }
                };
                if ( counter === 0) {
                    throw new Error('Empty message!');
                };
            }
        }
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
}, {
    sequelize:db,
    modelName: 'message',
    timestamps:true,
    updatedAt: false,
    indexes: [
        {
            fields: ['room_id']
        }, {
            fields: ['sender_id']
        }, {
            fields : ['receiver_id']
        } , {
            fields : ["type"]
        }
    ]
});
```

module.exports.Message = Message;

Comment: Somehow there must be a bug in your code, because the `INSERT` statement definitely tries to insert NULL.

Comment: Show a model definition

Comment: `Executing (default): INSERT INTO "messages" ("id","room_id","sender_id","type","data","createdAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id","room_id","sender_id","type","receiver_id","data","createdAt"; `. Here is part of the error

Comment: Your DB table is missing default value for `id` and that's why the value is not filled.  When you create it, it was missing `SERIAL` or some default setup.  How did you create the table in Postgres?